# RestClient mishandling the PAC for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, proxy, restsharp, jira-rest-api

I need to migrate an application (that is consuming a Jira API) to `.NET Core 3.1`

```
var JiraClient = Atlassian.Jira.Jira.CreateRestClient("url", "username", "password");
var JiraLogs = JiraClient.Issues.GetChangeLogsAsync("key").Result;
```

The REST client works fine both on `.NET Framework 4.8` and `.NET Core 2.2`, but raises an exception on .NET Core 3.1 ... is returning the whole PAC file instead of resolving for the proxy.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This PAC was web generated: 2020-05-23 10:50:39 AM
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var pacname = "hou9-hpx.pac";
var pacdate = "2020-05-23 10:50:39 AM";

function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
    {
    QNETPROXY = "PROXY proxy-ccy.company.net:8080; PROXY web-proxy.company.net:8080";
    HPROXY1 = "PROXY proxy-ccy.company.net:8080";
   }
```

- Why does this happens?
- How should I configure the proxy? (I tried setting up the proxy explicitly as shown below, but the result still fails)

`RestClient.Settings.Proxy = new WebProxy("proxy-ccy.company.net", 8080);`

**Note**: A colleage told me he vaguely remembers that .Net Core implementation of http stack is not based on windows on IE libraries and therefore javascript files are not supported (pac file), not sure if this is true, but it seems like the most reasonable option so far, still not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, Self Contained, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the issue? Please include as much detail as possible.

Comment: Done, I added the code I'm having problems with.